# how to add a "next fieldset" button to an add/edit form for a Dexterity Plone type

Tags: plone, fieldset, dexterity

I have a Dexterity type that has multiple fieldsets, and the built-in Javascript that allows showing one fieldset at a time when adding or editing is wonderful.

But I'd like to invite the user to walk through the fieldsets in sequence, so my ideal situation would not present the "Submit" button until the last fieldset was visible, instead presenting `NEXT>` or `<PREV` and `NEXT>` buttons until that last fieldset.

I gather that this is a behavior?  But I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to add it and how to control it.  I'm currently using the default EditForm, and I'd much prefer to just make a tiny tweak, but if it means dropping down to building the form myself, that's OK.  I just need to know whether that's the only way to get this addition, which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fieldsets can be rigged up to add 'previous' and 'next' buttons with some extra JavaScript magic. Here's what I use in a current project:

```
var prevnext = {
    formTabs: null,

    next: function() { prevnext.formTabs.data('tabs').next(); prevnext._scrollToTop(); },
    prev: function() { prevnext.formTabs.data('tabs').prev(); prevnext._scrollToTop(); },

    _scrollToTop: function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(prevnext.formTabs.closest('form').offset().top);  
    },

    showButtons: function(event, index) {
        var tabs = prevnext.formTabs.data('tabs'),
            index = typeof(index) === 'undefined' ? tabs.getIndex() : index,
            current = tabs.getTabs()[index],
            count = tabs.getTabs().length;

        $('#prevnext_previous').toggle(index !== 0);
        $('#prevnext_next').toggle(index !== (count - 1));

        $('.formControls:last :submit[name=form_submit]').toggle(index === )count - 1));
    },

    init: function() {
        var tabs;
        prevnext.formTabs = $('.formTabs');
        tabs = prevnext.formTabs.data('tabs');
        if (tabs.getTabs().length > 0) {
            if ($('fieldset#fieldset-distribution').length === 0)
                 return;
            $('.formControls:last :submit:first')
                .before($('<input id="prevnext_previous" class="context" ' +
                          '       type="button" value="" />')
                      .val('< Previous')
                      .click(prevnext.prev))
                .before(document.createTextNode(' '));
            $('.formControls:last :submit:first')
                .before($('<input id="prevnext_next" class="context" ' +
                          '       type="button" value="" />')
                      .val('Next >')
                      .click(prevnext.next))
                .before(document.createTextNode(' '));
            prevnext.showButtons();
            tabs.onClick(prevnext.showButtons);
        }
    }
};

$(prevnext.init());
```